# uppercase text in TextInput - react native

Tags: react-native

Good day, I need that when writing a text, the text in uppercase appeared by default. tried but failed

```js
<TextInput
autoCapitalize='none'
autoCorrect={false}
selectTextOnFocus={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be multiple ways to do it, i can tell you two simple ways to achieve this:

First:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder={'Enter value'}
   value={value}
   onChangeText={(text) => setValue(text.toUpperCase())}
   style={Styles.InputStyle}
   />
```

so we achieve this with onChangeText and set the props text to toUpperCase (string function). This will capitalize each characters while inserting into text input,

Second:

```
<TextInput
   placeholder={'Enter value'}
   value={value}
   autoCapitalize='characters'
   onChangeText={(text) => setValue(text)}
   style={Styles.InputStyle}
   />
```

**autoCapitalize** have different properties which we use them for different type of text handling,
e.g

1. 'none' : this will do no change to original text
2. 'characters' : this will capitalize each character.
3. 'sentences' : this will capitalize first character of a sentence.
4. 'words' : this will capitalize first character of each word.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: good morning, it gives me an error in setValue

Comment: set value is a state which you need to define as 
const [value,setValue]=React.useState('');